# Failed to execute postMessage on window on Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've made a custom throttle for ajax requests.

Problem is I keep getting this error?

---

*Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': 1 argument required, but only 0 present.*

---

The line points to `$.ajax({`.

HTML:

```
<input class="image_title" />
<span class="the_title"></span>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {

var aj_count = 0;
var aj_flag = false;
var aj_flag2 = false;
var run_on = -1;
setInterval(function() {
    aj_count++;

    if (aj_flag === true) {
        run_on = aj_count + 250;
        aj_flag = false;
        aj_flag2 = true;
    }

    if (run_on < aj_count && aj_flag2 === true) {

        var $t = $(this);
        var daid = $('.image_id').val();

        aj_flag2 = false;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/ajax/set_title.php',
            data: {
                'title' : $t,
                'id' : daid
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var data = JSON.parse(data);

                $('.the_title').html( '<small>Title:</small> <strong>' + data.title + '</strong>' );
            }
        });

    }
}, 1);

$('.image_title').on('input', function(e) {
    aj_flag = true;

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});

$('.image_title').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});

});
```

[image]

As you can see I have tried moving direct form vals into variables etc but I cannot get it to work anymore. When I replace the ajax section with a console.log it runs as expected. I've been looking around but I don't really understand what the error means still as ajax has an array passed to it.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Where is the call to `postMessage()` that's getting the error?

Comment: The video goes too quick, I can't figure out what you're trying to show. But `postMessage()` has nothing to do with AJAX.

Comment: It's within jQuery, see stacktrace: https://i.gyazo.com/3ef3d794da8a925917d5d15c1e9f9ce7.png

Comment: Change the video to .mp4 and you will have video controls to pause/slow down, thank you!

Comment: I just checked the source code to jQuery, it never calls `postMessage()`.

Comment: Since the backtrace is for minified jQuery, it's hard to tell where it is within jQuery.

Comment: @Kaiido Unfortunately it never makes the request

Comment: I tried changin `.gif` to `.mpf` in the image URL, I got an error message.

Comment: The error is happening in `$.param()`. I think the problem is because of `title: $t`. `$t` is `$(this)`, you can't serialize a jQuery object.

Comment: What are you expecting `$(this)` to be inside a `setInterval()` function, anyway?

Comment: It was caused by that random `$(this)`. Thank you @barmer well spotted. Thank you too @Kaiido for your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is probably because of

```
        var $t = $(this);
```

You're trying to send `$t` as the value of the `title:` parameter with

```
data: {
    title: $t,
    id: daid
},
```

But a jQuery object can't be serialized into a POST parameter.

You need to set `$t` to a proper title string. I don't know where that is in your application, but that should fix it.

Comment: And for the why it complained about `postMessage`, it's because `$.param()` calls the methods it will find https://jsfiddle.net/2L4jke8d/, which is very weird IMM.

Comment: Yeah, see this comment in the source code: `// If value is a function, invoke it and use its return value`

Comment: This allows you to write `data: { foo: function() { $("#bar").val() } }`. This is useful when you want to create the `data:` parameter once and have the values fill in dynamically.